# Which is created first between variables and methods during the creation of a class?

Tags: c#, oop, class

I'm just curious about which among variables and methods inside a class were initialized first whenever a class is initialized. I have this code below to give you idea of what I am really troubled of:

```
 public static class
 {
    private static int _revisionNumber;
    private static Dictionary<string, bool> _jobBoardList;
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = GetAppConfigData("JobBoardAutomationConnectionString");
    private static readonly string ImportRunId = JobProcessingUtility.GetGuid();
    private static readonly string TimeStampGuidString = CreateTimeStampGuidString(ImportRunId);
    private static string _tempDirectoryForExportFiles;
    ........

    private static string GetAppConfigData(string key)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
    }
 }
```

You can notice that i have a variable named **"ConnectionString"** and it is acquiring it's value from the method named **GetAppConfigData(string key)**, I'm just curious of which among methods and variables inside a class were created first whenever a class(not instances of the class) is initialized. Can someone please explain to me which was constructed first so that I could have a good idea of how to create classes and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables are initialized in textual order (i.e. the order in source code), as per section 10.5.5 of the C# 4 specification:

> Thus, when a class is initialized, all static fields in that class are first initialized to their default values, and then the static field initializers are executed in textual order.

So in your case, the initializer for `ConnectionString` would be executed before `JobProcessingUtility.GetGuid()` is called.

However, it's generally not a good idea to rely on this, as it makes the code brittle - the simple act of reordering static variables could break the code. I've come across situations where it's somewhat hard to avoid, but where possible you *should* avoid it.

Note that when there is still room for ambiguity with partial classes - the spec doesn't make any guarantees there, although I'd *expect* all the static fields declared in one source file to be initialized, then all the ones in the other(s) to be initialized, with the order preserved within each source file. But no guarantees :)

Comment: Can you give me an example for the situations that you have experienced with regards to this topic.

Comment: @AllanChua: In Noda Time, we have various calendar systems including ISO. I had a singleton for the ISO calendar which was in the CalendarSystem type, but initializing that created an instance of IsoCalendarSystem which relied on something else already being initialized... it ended up being a real pain to debug.

Comment: @Allan: *always* avoid depending on textual order of static initializers — if stuff needs to happen in order, put it in the static constructor. Otherwise you will be bequeathing a source of bugs and head-scratching to those who come after.

Answer (score 2):

<s>The order is implementation-defined.</s> Your code should not depend on the order of initialization. If initializers for some of your static member variables must execute in a certain order, put them in the static constructor.

Comment: It's not implementation-defined - it's in the spec.

Comment: You're right, so it is. Nevertheless I believe it is bad practice to depend on it — I believe this so strongly that I even forgot about the spec :3

Answer (score 1):

All the fields which are initialized on declaration become a part of a constructor. There are two types of constructors: static and non-static. Non-static is called on object initialization and static is called before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

Comment: Hi, can you give me a reference where you have gained knowledge with this :)

Comment: Try inside a debug mode - it would very demonstrative. But I recommend reading books "C# in a Nutshell" and "C# in depth", actually I do read them now and close a lot of gaps in my knowledge of the language

Answer (score 0):

Methods cannot be initialzed! (Whatfor?) Static members are initialized before the static construcor is called and instance members are initialized before the instance constructor is called.

Comment: uhmm i see. let me replace it with a non static ones thanks :)